# Altrnative to KDE's "force font dpi" functionality

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, kde, dpi

I am currently using a non-KDE system (Lubuntu) and am trying to find a way to *force* DPI to a specific value. What file do I need to edit to force dpi to 96? What is the proper code?

My Ubuntu system oddly enough comes without any xorg.conf file.

Thanks!

Comment: Run the command `xrandr --dpi 96` . Do you see any difference ? If yes, then place the command as a startup application.

Comment: Having to `xorg.conf` is normal nowadays since the configuration is automatic. I tried that `xrandr` command and did not see any difference, though.